# Direct sum of torsion modules, counterexample?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $x \in R - \{0\},$ where $R$ is a domain.

Define $T_x(M) = \{m \in M \ | \ x^n m=0 \ \ \mathrm{for \ some} \ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ as the $x$-torsion of $M.$

I need to show that $T_x(M \oplus N) = T_x(M) \oplus T_x(N)$ for $R$-modules $M,N$ or show that there is a counterexample.

Is my proof correct?

Take $(a,b)\in T_x(M\oplus N)$. Then there exist $m,n \in \mathbb{N},$ not necessarily equal, such that $x^m a + x^n b=0.$ Take $(a,b)\in T_x(M) \oplus T_x(N)$. Then there exist $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^m a=0$ and $x^n b=0.$ So if $(a,b)\in T_x(M) \oplus T_x(N),$ then $(a,b)\in T_x(M\oplus N).$ But the converse is not true. Thus $T(M \oplus N) \neq T(M) \oplus T(N).$

Comment: @user26857 Please see edits.

Comment: Is this correct then: Take $$(a,b)\in T_x(M \oplus N) = \{a \in M, \ b \in N  \ | \ (x^m a, x^m b)=(0,0) \ \ \mathrm{for \ some} \ m \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$ Then $x^m a = 0, x^m b = 0.$ So if $(a,b)\in T_x(M\oplus N),$ then $(a,b)\in T_x(M) \oplus T_x(N).$

Now take $(a,b)\in T_x(M) \oplus T_x(N)$. Then there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^m a=0$ and $x^m b=0.$ So if $(a,b)\in T_x(M) \oplus T_x(N),$ then $(a,b)\in T_x(M\oplus N).$

Thus $T(M \oplus N) = T(M) \oplus T(N).$